# Implementing a 8X1 multiplexer using two 4X1 multiplexer

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, logic-gates

"Obtain an 8 X 1 multiplexer with a dual 4-line to 1-line multiplexers having separate enable inputs but common selection lines. Use a block diagram construction."

This is a question i came across recently . now the doubt i am having here is that can we just implement it by assuming that mux has a enable pin .I mean is there any other way of implementing it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.  You either need enable pins on the MUXes, or you need a 2 to 1 MUX on the output.  Seems like the problem statement explicitly mentions enable lines, so that's probably the solution they're looking for.  If you are targeting a particular architecture (e.g. FPGA) then one of these may make more sense.  For instance, you can't do tristates within an FPGA, so you would need to use a 2 to 1 mux.  On an ASIC, you might be able to use a tristate, but you could pay for it in timing performance.  With discrete TTL logic, tristate is probably the simplest implementation if the muxes have output enables.